# @html.TextBoxFor model value is not setting/prefilled/appearing for the type date

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, datepicker

I have an `@html.TextBoxFor` where the type I have specified is date. On rendering the view the model value (which is coming from database) is not setting.

My code looks as follows.

```html
<tr>
  <td>@Html.Label("ReferenceId")</td>
  <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ReferenceId, new { @class = "form-control" })</td>
  <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ReferenceId, null, new { @style = "color:red" })</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>@Html.Label("End Date")</td>
  <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EndDate, "{0:MM/dd/YYYY}", new { @class = "form-control", type = "date"})</td>
  <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.EndDate, null, new { @style = "color:red" })</td>
</tr>
```

This is how view looks after loading model data:

[image]

As it can be seen reference id is populating but date is not. I need help in setting model value to the date field.

Comment: when you inspect the field what is the "value" attribute set to?  I think you'll want yyyy-mm-dd... so today's value should say "2021-05-07"... otherwise the browser just puts in mm/dd/yyyy as the default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EndDate, "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", new { @class = "form-control", type = "date"})
```

Should work. I strongly recommend create a custom Helper using HtmlHelper for this scenarios.

```
public static MvcHtmlString DateFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> date, string type = "date", string format = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")
        {
            var value = (DateTime?)ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(date, html.ViewData).Model;

            var div = new TagBuilder("div");
            div.AddCssClass("input-group");

            var span = new TagBuilder("span");
            span.Attributes.Add("style", "color:black");
            span.AddCssClass("input-group-addon");
            span.InnerHtml = "<i class='fa fa-calendar'></i>";
            div.InnerHtml = span.ToString();
            if (format != "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")
            {
                div.InnerHtml += html.TextBoxFor(date, format, new { @class = "form-control", @type = type, data_date_format = format }).ToHtmlString();
            }
            else {
                div.InnerHtml += html.TextBoxFor(date, format, new { @class = "form-control", @type = type }).ToHtmlString();
            }
            
            return new MvcHtmlString(div.ToString());
        }
```